# Batch wont execute but just re-print its content

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

No matter what my code is, even if my batch file is syntactically incorrect, even if it is absolutely correct and even if there is nothing to display on the screen the batch file when executed just displays the code as it is.

I read a similar question [MSDOS prints the whole batch file on screen instead of executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36412999/msdos-prints-the-whole-batch-file-on-screen-instead-of-executing) but since that was on MS-DOS I hoped my issue could have a solution different than that.

Eg,

```
@echo off
set abcd=4
```

Even its batch file would just display the same lines as it is.
Please help.

Comment: How are you executing your batch file? From the command line? Double clicking? What command are you using to start it?

Comment: I tried both the ways. Still the same result. From the command line and also by Double clicking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try "*resetting*" cmd if possible. U can try copying someone else's "**cmd.exe**" and replace it with yours using another bootable OS as windows wont allow that.

Here use my **cmd.exe**. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6ghonMKBfUSLVpRV0U5bG5pQTQ
Just in case u need to know I am using Windows 10 64 bit.

Comment: Isn't it risky to do so? Though thumbs up for providing your own cmd.exe

Comment: I can not be very certain about that but in the other case u need to format your pc. (I personally recommend you to try it though not guarantee it)

Comment: OK i'm willing to take the risk as your answer is the only hope.

Answer (score 1):

To determine whether your issue is really with line breaks being converted by your text editor (as the post you mention suggests), perform the following test:

- Open a Command Line Window
- Type the following command: **copy con test.bat**
- The cursor will reposition itself under the command prompt, this is normal
- Type the following 3 commands, each followed by the [Enter] key:

.

```
Echo Off
Set abcd=4
Echo abcd
```

- Press **CTRL-Z** simultaneously (it will show up on screen as **^Z**)
- A confimation message should state: *1 file(s) copied.*

Now type **Test** to run the batch file. If it runs properly, it means you are indeed dealing with line termination issues. Use a different text editor (don't use Notepad!!!), ideally one where you have an option to display the line termination characters (I personnally use NotePad++, it works great for these kinds of things but there are many others out there).

Comment: Thanks for your help but still the same thing. The batch opens and reprints itself. And I am definitely sere I am not dealing with line termination issues.

Answer (score 1):

Check the file with an editor that allows you to see the encoding.
For example Notepad++ , you will see is very different the end of line via CF (\r) and LF (\n)

Your CMD can be recognizing EOL via \n only.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is a problem with your environment variables. Check the following:

1. Press WIN + R and run "%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe"
2. Click on "Environment Variables"
3. The system variables are listed at the bottom. Select the variable "Path" and click "Edit..."
4. Check whether the list contains "C:\Windows\System32" or "%SYSTEMROOT%\System32". If not, add one of those. You may have to restart your computer afterwards.